# Generate GLTF/OBJ models from quantized mesh (terrain) in CesiumJS?

Tags: terrain, cesium, mesh, quantized-mesh

I’m exploring ways to generate gltf / obj models from terrain mesh. My goal is to show 3d cut-fill volume calculation, something like the following -

[image]

I realized that I don’t need to DEM to generate GLTF models. Terrain mesh already has all necessary information, if I can load this mesh in some tool and export it as GLTF/OBJ, that’ll solve the problem -

[image]

I've opened a topic in Cesium community, you can find more details and my progress here - https://community.cesium.com/t/terrain-mesh-to-gltf-models/17209